# Ignore nulls columns while making an array with struct

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I added a column to a dataframe which is an array of other columns.

[image: strong text]

How can I ignore the null values when I construct the column name_source? For example the line for `Robert` would show `[internet, Robert]` instead of `[internet, Robert,]`. The one with null name would show `[internet,65878]`  instead of `[internet,, 65878]`

Comment: Please let me know the answer given with filter works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same as follows:

```
df = df.withColumn('name_source', expr('filter(name_source, x -> x is not null)'))
```

**Scala:**

```
df.select(filter(col("name_source"), x => x.isNotNull))
```

Comment: can you please provide in scala version

Comment: @LearnHadoop I have updated the answer, could you check whether that helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create your new column from all the ones in the initial dataframe:

```
df["name_source"] = df.apply(lambda x : x.dropna().values, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array all the rows and the array except the None after you cast it to string

```
df.withColumn("name_source",array(*[c for c in df.columns ])).withColumn("name_source",array_except(col('name_source'),array(lit(None).cast('string')))).show(truncate=False)
```